# Does Lwaxana Troi ever talk to herself (as the computer voice)?

Tags: star-trek, actors

They were both played by Majel Barrett-Roddenberry, but I can't remember if she ever interacted with a Federation computer. Which would be a nice in-joke if it happened.

Comment: Nice question!  I never thought about this.

Comment: Additional info but not answer worthy: In the Animated Series, Majel voiced Nurse Chapel. In the episode "The Lorelai Signal", Nichele Nichols voiced the computer (whereas Majel was generally the computer)

Comment: Lwaxana Troi was played by Majel Barrett? My mind is blown.

Comment: She was also the first officer ("Number One") in the original pilot "The Cage"

Comment: I wonder if people who record telephone voice menus have a similar experience when they dial in to a company they recorded for (and *eg* tell themselves "to pay your bill, press 2...")

Comment: @Crashworks It is weird - especially when you forgot that you recorded it, or if you recorded it for a client (as the phone system vendor) and you forgot and you call the client and get the phone tree and it takes you 30 seconds to realize you're talking to yourself.

Comment: @Crashworks: A related situation: people who do telemarketing also occasionally have the bizarre experience of leaving sales call messages for themselves when they are connected to their own answering machines.  Or at least they were, back in the days when people had land lines with answering machines.

Comment: Shame she's not around to lend her voice to the new series' computer.

Comment: This is much more common in cartoons of course, where it's so much more common to play multiple parts. For example every conversation between Burns and Smithers in the Simpsons, as they're both voiced by Harry Shearer, or the Family Guy episode "Brian and Stewie" in which the whole cast got the day off and Seth McFarlane plays a one-hander.

Comment: @Dan actually Majel recorded a set of phoenetic sounds before she died so that her voice could be accurately synthesized for the Star Fleet computers in the future.  http://nerdist.com/the-late-majel-barrett-may-voice-star-trek-discoverys-computer/

Answer (score 96, accepted):

### Yes.

Twice in fact.

From TNG Season 2 Episode 19, [*Manhunt*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manhunt_(Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation)) (transcript [here](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/145.htm)):

> LWAXANA: Hello, computer? Is Commander Riker still on the Bridge?
>   COMPUTER: Negative. Riker is currently in holodeck three.
>   LWAXANA: Holodeck? Where is that?
>   COMPUTER: Follow the comm. panel lights. They will lead you there.

From TNG Season 5 Episode 20, [*Cost of Living*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cost_of_Living_(Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation)) (transcript [here](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/220.htm)):

> LWAXANA: I'll bet you've never been to a colony of free spirits.
>   ALEXANDER: What do they do there?
>   LWAXANA: Whatever they want. Artists, philosophers, free thinkers and people who don't quite fit other people's rules. Personally, I come for the mud baths. You, oh, you're going to adore the mud baths. Computer? I'm assuming you have the Parallax Colony of Shiralea VI?
>   COMPUTER: That programme is available.
>   LWAXANA: Oh, good. Then run it for us, dear.

Comment: Ha! She even called herself "dear"