# Who is the most recurring Star Trek character who was always themselves?

Tags: star-trek, holodeck, mirror-universe, changeling

Impersonation, simulation, alternate universes and general xeno- and techno-shenanigans are a mainstay of the *Star Trek* franchises.

It occurred to me that I can't really think of a main character who was not subject to:

- recreation on a holodeck
- impersonation by aliens
- depiction in the Mirror Universe or another parallel universe

For example,

> *TNG* has most characters excluded in "Parallels".   *DS9* has most characters excluded by its five Mirror Universe episodes, not to mention the Changelings.  Voyager had an entire ship and crew impersonated in "Course: Oblivion".   Most of *Enterprise* is covered by "These Are The Voyages".   And many characters in *Discovery* have been depicted in their Mirror Universe forms.

## Who is the most recurring character who has always been themselves?

---

In order to disambiguate, I'm going to consider "not being oneself" to mean we never saw cases where:

1. It looked like character X, but wasn't actually "the real" character X, or
2. It looked like character X and was the body of character X, but X wasn't in control, or
3. Character X assumed the role of character Y, or,
4. The usual appearance of X is not the true appearance of X to begin with.
5. X was sufficiently disembodied or re-embodied.   (Turning into a lizard or an energy field or de-aging by 30 years)

---

Just in case it's not clear, in-universe pictures, viewscreen depictions, holographic communication technology, etc do not count as not being oneself.

In case of ambiguity about whether a particular situation counts or not, please ask for clarification in the comments or [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73049/discussion-on-question-by-thepopmachine-who-is-the-most-recurring-star-trek-char), and I'll try to hone the question.

Comment: The entire crew of the TOS Enterprise was [evil for an episode](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Mirror_universe). The entire crew of the NX-01 Enterprise were [evil for an episode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_a_Mirror,_Darkly). The entire crew of the Voyager were [evil for an episode](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Living_Witness_(episode)) as were [the entire DS9 crew](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Through_the_Looking_Glass_(episode))

Comment: It's going to need to be someone who is quite recurring, but luckily avoided each instance of shenanigans?

Comment: What constitutes a different self? Lwaxana appears as a younger version of herself in her mind in Dark Page, Keiko gets age regressed in a TNG episode, many of the crew become protohumanoids in Genesis, etc. They are still themselves, yet not the actual character.

Comment: *main character who was not subject to:* #4 genetic modification.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73049/discussion-on-question-by-thepopmachine-who-is-the-most-recurring-star-trek-char). (Seriously, guys? **40 comments** in <45 minutes?)

Comment: *<20 more comments deleted>* Take the discussion to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73049/discussion-on-question-by-thepopmachine-who-is-the-most-recurring-star-trek-char).

Comment: Criteria 5 [also eliminates the whole TNG crew in one episode](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Genesis_(episode)) (except for Picard/Data, and they have plenty disqualifying instances themselves)

Answer (score 34):

**Jake Sisko**

Ben and Jennifer Sisko have a different marriage / separation timeline in the Mirror universe, and Jake does not have a Mirror counterpart.

Appearances list: (listed as **71** appearances)

Reference: ["Jake Sisko", *Memory Alpha*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Jake_Sisko)

(note: Jake was not 'impersonated' by an alien, but was possessed by a wormhole alien, but all the characters knew it was happening, so there was no deception occurring)

Comment: Are we also not counting the times when Benjamin Sisko was communing with the Prophets and one of them appeared as Jake Sisko? It wasn't deliberate deception, but it took Benjamin a little while to figure out what was going on.

Comment: @Shufflepants - I mentioned it in the (apparenlty moved comments), and a few others did as well. Additionally, at the time I answered, that wasn't one of the exclusions. Not sure who moved the comments, but given the debatable nature of the question and this answer, it was probably more helpful to have them available rather than move them

Comment: Here's some footage of Jake being portrayed by a wormhole alien in a prophet vision; https://youtu.be/aYnSIjuJtKU?t=2m21s

Comment: [Disqualified by criteria 1](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/The_Search,_Part_II_(episode)), as part of the simulation to deceive the landing party.

Answer (score 15):

Jokingly - **The ship computer**

> Star Treks' original series, The Next Generation, Deep Space Nine, and Voyager all have one actor in common: Majel Barrett-Roddenberry (wife of Star Trek creator Gene Roddenberry)

Always the voice of the ship, even when the ship wasn't a ship (hologram, mind game, recreation, etc).

---

Slightly more serious would be Lwaxana Troi. Appeared in 9 different episodes across two different series and I believe was always herself.

Comment: if there was a mirror enterprise, there was a mirror computer...I'm not going to downvote this but...

Comment: Which is also interesting, since Lwaxana Troi and the Ship Computer are both Majel Barrett.

Comment: The Corbin Bernsen Q is a separate entity to the John de Lancie Q.  He's not the same Q, he's a different member of that species.  If you recall the episode, it was the rest of the Q who stripped JdL Q of his powers and exiled him from the continuum.

Comment: @Mwr247 Indeed - [she even talks to herself](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/128918/31394) a couple of times!

Comment: @NKCampbell: but the mirror universe computer used a male voice, so does that still count as the same character?

Comment: eh - maybe. But, according to the latest update from OP, the computer is a no-go due to the episode "The Practical Joker" thanks to an alien entity taking over the computer

Comment: There was a Ship's Computer in "Parallels".   Plus the computer impersonates people all the time (holodeck).   And this is ignoring the question of whether it even counts as a character (it doesn't).   You know -- if we're going to be pedantic about a joking answer.     @MivaScott even states it's a joking answer.

Comment: @Valorum, removed all Q stuff as it didn't add anything

Comment: You might want to note that there were fake Enterprise computers seen (or rather heard) in **TNG: Ship in a Bottle** (the fact that it wasn't the real computer was a plot-point), **TNG: Remember Me** (Where the entire ship was a fiction in Dr. Crusher's mind) and **TNG: Future Imperfect** with the latter being a complete fiction created by an alien.

Answer (score 14):

**Guinan**

Not only has Guinan never (afaik) appeared on a holodeck as a hologram, when we see parallel universes (like in [Yesterday's Enterprise](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Yesterday%27s_Enterprise_(episode))), she is the only one aware that the universe has changed, and retains the memory of those events as well.

Comment: *"[I can't leave. I'm there already, Remember?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hkk-IYaXlVQ&feature=youtu.be&t=6m20s)"*

Comment: Picard talked to an echo of Guinan in the Nexus (Star Trek Generations), also waiting on clarification of the age regression.

Comment: Also - In Hollow Pursuits, there is a holodeck recreation of Guinan @Valorum

Answer (score 9):

**Gowron**

Gowron was a recurring character in TNG and DS9, appearing in 12 episodes. I cannot find a single instance where the character Gowron appeared as anyone but himself.  Robert O'Reilly did appear in several Star Trek episodes as another character entirely and not as Gowron or in costume as Gowron.

[Robert O'Reilly on Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Robert_O%27Reilly)

[Gowron on Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Gowron)

Comment: per OP comments on my answer, the actor appearing as another character should disqualify him. --  "I think it is correct that "Far Beyond the Stars" eliminates Jake Sisko"

Comment: @NKCampbell:   Well, I'm not so sure about that.   I was thinking that the existence of someone in "Far Beyond the Stars" on whom Jake Sisko may be based is the thing that eliminates him.   I.e. there's a different version of Jake Sisko and we don't really know which is "real".   But Gowron didn't appear in that episode, did he?

Comment: Answer should say how many episodes Gowron appeared in.   And does everyone agree he always was himself?

Comment: added the number of episodes

Comment: No, @ThePopMachine - but Robert O'Reilly appeared as a human accountant in 'Badda-Bing, Badda-Bang' which is no different than Ciroc Lofton appearing as Jimmy in FBtS

Comment: @ThePopMachine: The character Gowron was in 11 episodes, 4 on TNG/7 on DS9. Never as a hologram, changeling (though suspected for an episode or two) or a prophet talking to Sisko. The ACTOR played multiple roles but never an alternate version of Gowron (no mirror universe counterpart, Far Beyond the Stars "adaptation" etc.

Comment: Yes, the issue is not the actor playing multiple roles.   That is fair game.   The issue we're struggling with is only what exactly FBtS means.   But that episode was intentionally ambiguous.   The episode "makes you think".   It is hard to make a ruling.   But @NKCampbell, can we just put that one to bed because Jake is out due to Prophet Possession anyhow.

Comment: I thought for sure Gowron was once in a prophet vision but I can't find one. Martok is in a couple

Comment: Rand is tied w/ Gowron at 12 (includes movies)

Answer (score 6):

Tribbles.

They have been in 12 episodes or movies.

And they are always tribbles.

As a tribble reproduces through parthenogenesis (dividing itself), every tribble is a branch of the ur-tribble.

Hear us coo, and despair.

Comment: The tribble is...er, trouble is, they aren't characters. They are props.

Comment: not canon, but it is funny: https://qmxonline.com/products/star-trek-mirror-universe-tribble

Comment: @EricDraven Well now you have to decide what defines a character. Was Spot a character or a prop?

Comment: @corsiKa According to Brent Spiner [the worst actor he ever worked with](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vhTNWBRZYR8), so maybe a character :P

Comment: @BMWurm Spot has been in 10 episodes.  So fewer than Tribbles.

Comment: @Yakk Spot was once a lizard. Also, if we're counting pets as characters, I have to think Archer's dog appeared in more episodes.

Comment: @Shufflepants how cold blooded of the show writers.

Comment: @Shufflepants There are too many alternative timeline episodes on Enterprise for me to believe Porthos never showed up in one.  Even Picard's fish was mutated.  O'Brian's cat is in two episodes...

Answer (score 5):

Assuming it really was [Q](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Q) in [Tapestry](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Tapestry_(episode)) and not God posing as Q, then Q, played by John Delancie appeared in 8 episodes of TNG, 1 episode of DS9 and 3 episodes of Voyager.

There has never been a hologram or other representation of Q. The only potential hiccup is in in the Voyager episode [Q2](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Q2_(episode)) in which Q takes the form of a Chokuzan commander and is played by a different actor. That said, it is still Q trying to teach his son a lesson.

Comment: Being played by a different actor is not material.   The fact is that Q took on a different appearance.   Someone who you one could think wasn't Q turned out to be Q.   That is impersonation plain and simple.

Comment: Then I stand by my answer